# Wordpress Widgets are either not showing or are incomplete

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress theme that is having an issue with widgets.  So far, I only have I sidebar with 3 widgets: "Search", "Recent Posts", and "Categories".  However, the "Categories" widget only displays 1 category (there should be 4).  And it says that 1 category has 2 posts, even though there are 4 registered to it.

I tried working around this by creating a custom menu with links to all four categories.  But NONE of those links show up, in either the admin or non-admin views.  Does anybody have any idea what is going on?

This is what is in my functions.php:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
register_sidebar(array(
  'name' => __('Sidebar 1', 'builder'),
  'id' => 'sidebar-1',
  'before_widget' => '',
  'after_widget' => '',
  'before_title' => '<h2>',
  'after_title' => '</h2>',
));
```

this is in my header.php file:

```
dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' );
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are the posts that are not shown published? Or draft?

Comment: They are all published.  I don't have any posts that are drafts

Comment: if this is your custom widget then you have to change id during register sidebar because of sidebar-1 already  taken in sidebar.